# How to write a NOT IN statement for YEAR in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Who are those users who are not born in 1997?

```
SELECT userFname, userLname, userDOB
FROM user
WHERE userDOB IN YEAR(1997);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are any of the [userDOB] values empty or null or otherwise not of a Date/Time data type?  You may need to accommodate such.  Also, I would use syntax with YEAR(userDOB) != 1997

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing userDOB is a Date

```
SELECT userFname, userLname, userDOB
FROM user
WHERE YEAR(userDOB) NOT IN (1997);
```

Answer (score 1):

Keep things easy:

`YEAR(yourDate)` returns only the year of `yourDate`.

Then, to find out all *users who are not born in 1997*, simply

```
SELECT userFname, userLname, userDOB
FROM user
WHERE YEAR(userDOB) <> 1997
```

Answer (score 1):

The purist part of me is objecting to the current answers that use the `YEAR` function.  Why?  Because the use of a function makes the condition ignore the index, that's why.

So, then, the answer is normally to use a function to create the range:

```
SELECT userFname, userLname, userDOB
FROM user
WHERE userDOB >= CAST('1997-01-01' AS DATE)
      AND userDOB < CAST('1998-01-01' AS DATE)
```

... except you actually want the reverse, so let's switch the conditions:

```
SELECT userFname, userLname, userDOB
FROM user
WHERE userDOB < CAST('1997-01-01' AS DATE)
      OR userDOB >= CAST('1998-01-01' AS DATE)
```

... and at this point my purism doesn't matter quite so much.  Why?  Because of the percentage of rows (likely to be) selected, and the data unlikely to be in the same index ([Check the third point here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/table-scan-avoidance.html)).

Answer (score 0):

you should use trhe YEAR() function for convert your date column and you can use not in   for  check several value

```
SELECT userFname, userLname, userDOB
FROM user
WHERE year(userDOB) NOT IN  (1997, 1998);
```

but if you have only a value you don't need  IN (or not in)  but =

```
SELECT userFname, userLname, userDOB
FROM user
WHERE year(userDOB) <>  1997;
```